# Android SQLITE only written when debugging

Tags: android, sqlite

I am currently using an implementation of IntentService to fetch JSON from the network, parse it and insert into a database using a ContentProvider. I am getting some very inconsistent results. When I run the application nothing gets inserted into the db, but when I debug all the records get inserted properly. When running in real time I am writing the parsed JSON to the Log and it shows up fine. It just won't write to the db without being in the debugger. Has anyone experienced an issue like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally I had 2 IntentServices running, one to fetch some JSON and insert it into the database and the other to fetch some large images. Originally I thought it would be best to start them both at the same time, it appears this was a bad idea. As soon as I disabled the image fetching service all the database writes and reads have been working fine.

This solves my original problem but doesn't answer any of the questions for me like how many separate services can run at once or is SQlite really thread safe. Anyways, if someone happens uppon this that was my solution.